# How can I prevent two shell scripts running at the same time?

Tags: bash, scripts, reboot, cron, tar

I have a `tar` backup script that runs once a month. It runs at night through `cron`. I also have a power schedule that reboots the server at 4.15 every night.

The problem is that the server reboots while the `tar` script is running.

Can I add something to the beginning and end of a bash script to disable a reboot while the script is active?

Comment: … run the script earlier?

Answer (score 3):

There is a discussion of how to implement a mutex lock in the Bash FAQs here:

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/045

You could implement something similar, but make your reboot script loop until the lock is free. I haven't tested the following, but here's a starting point:

Tar script:

```
#!/bin/bash

lockdir=/tmp/myscript.lock

if mkdir "$lockdir"
then    # directory did not exist, but was created successfully
    echo >&2 "successfully acquired lock: $lockdir"
    trap 'rm -rf "$lockdir"' 0    # remove directory when script finishes
    # continue script
else
    echo >&2 "cannot acquire lock, giving up on $lockdir"
    exit 0
fi

# DO YOUR ORIGINAL TAR SCRIPT HERE
```

Reboot script:

```
#!/bin/bash

lockdir=/tmp/myscript.lock

while true; do
    if mkdir "$lockdir"
    then    # directory did not exist, but was created successfully
        trap 'rm -rf "$lockdir"' 0    # remove directory when script finishes
        break    # continue with script
    else
        sleep 5  # sleep for 5 seconds and try again
    fi
done

# RUN YOUR REBOOT COMMANDS HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use polling technique for the pid of that script. Basic idea is wait until the script releases the PID  (meaning it has exited), and only then go to the next step in the reboot script. And of course if no process is running, the script will go on to reboot.

```
#!/bin/bash
while pgrep -f my_backup_script_name.sh > /dev/null
do 
  sleep 0.25  # small delay so that the loop doesn't hog the CPU
done
shutdown -r now
```